# Absolutely positioned element inside fixed positioned element

Tags: jquery, html, css

Related to my previous question, I have a `<div style="position: fixed;">` footer. The footer contains `<a style="display: block; float: left;">` elements. Upon clicking one of these links I want a div to popup above that link. I am experimenting with a couple of CSS settings and got acceptable results but I am not sure if my CSS will work across browsers. I am wondering if some one can tell me a bullet proof and tested CSS solution to achieve something like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You could use JavaScript to traverse DOM and find the position of the anchor tag.  You could then move the div's left to the anchor's left and bottom to the anchor's top...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged jQuery, jQueryUI has a utility that offers support for that sort of positioning.

You don't actually need the rest of jQueryUI installed (even core). You just need jQuery. If you don't want the rest of jQueryUI, at the download page, de-select all, then select **Position** under **UI Core**.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/

*"Utility script for absolutely positioning any widget relative to the window, document, a particular element, or the cursor/mouse."*